# selecting values from two tables using union but with different key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, union

I have two tables: teacher-record and student-record.

```
teacher-record has two columns: teacher_id, email (email of teacher)
student-record has two columns: student_id, email (email of student)
```

I am trying to select teacher_id and student_id using single query by using a union.

This is the MySQL query I used (I am also using codeignitor).

```
public function get_std_tech_id($std_email, $tech_email)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT `student_id` AS std FROM `student-record` WHERE `email`= '$std_email'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT `teacher_id` AS tech FROM `teacher-record` WHERE `email` ='$tech_email'");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Now, the result array I get is this:

```
Array ( [std] => SID2016063(student_id) ) Array ( [std] => TECH20160922(teacher_id) )
```

What I am trying or get is like this:

```
Array ( [std] => SID2016063 ) Array ( [tech] => TECH20160922 )
```

How can I get a result like this?

Comment: UNION needs same column name, you can add a 2nd column specifying what type of `id` is this.

Comment: can you please explain in detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNION won't allow you this, it needs same column name.

You can add a 2nd column containing what type of id that specific row contains:

```
SELECT `student_id` AS id, 'std' AS type FROM `student-record` WHERE `email`= '$std_email' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT `teacher_id` AS id, 'tech' AS type FROM `teacher-record` WHERE `email` ='$tech_email'
```

then in php you can differentiate the results based on the column `type`.

PS: I am not a PHP guy so I can't predict in what format this dataset will come.

Comment: worked fine and very well you peoples are awesome spontaneous very helpful and the answer was well explained much appreciating

Comment: in php i did foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
   if($value['type'] === 'std')
   {
    echo 'your are student with id'.$value['id'];
    echo'</br>';
   }
   elseif ($value['type'] === 'tech') {
    echo 'you are teacher with id'.$value['id'];
   }
  } with help of you